# BLOB data is not displaying in UITextView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, sqlite, uitextview

**hello**,

I am stucked at the last part of it, Please help me on it.

In this there are **three views**, **first** one, for **list of books**( in **UITableView**), **second** is **chapters**(in **UITableView**) and **last** one is for **content**,which is in text format (in **UITextView**).

Upto second view it is working very fine.**Problem** is, when i select any chapters in second view, text view in third view **displays nothing**.But in output it displays the sequence of numbers.

code to fetch data from database and display into UITextView.

```
 NSMutableString *mStr = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"select content from content where name = \"%@\" and chapterno = %@",chapName,chapNo];
 const char *sql =(char *)[mStr UTF8String];

    sqlite3_stmt *sqlStmt;
    if(sqlite3_prepare(dbContent, sql, -1, &sqlStmt, NULL)!=SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"prob with prepare statement: %s",sqlite3_errmsg(dbContent));
    }
    else
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(sqlStmt)==SQLITE_ROW) {
            len = sqlite3_column_bytes(sqlStmt, 0);
            NSData *cData = [[NSData alloc]initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(sqlStmt, 0) length:len];

            NSString *nstr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[cData bytes]];
            myTextView.text = nstr;
  }
```

In above **chapName** is coming from **first view** and **chapNo** is selected row in **second view**.

content table looks like:

```
 id      bookid      name       chapterno          content

  1        1          abc           1            BLOB(size:4217)  
  2        1          abc           2            BLOB(size:3193)
  3        1          abc           3            BLOB(size:3501)
```

O/p comes in a long sequence of numbers like this..

```
  <0d0a3120 496e2074 68652062 6567696e 6e696e67 20476f64 20637265 61746564 20746865 20686561 76656e20 616e6420 74686520 65617274 682e0d0a...>
```

Here, text content i need to display in text view. What i'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is NSData to NSString conversion. If your Sqlite strings are not null-terminated converting with following line should help.

```
NSString* nStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:cData
                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have already tried this before using this(NSString *nstr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[cData bytes]];)line..Didn't work out.

Comment: No. There is a significant difference. UTF8String should be used if the string is null terminated. Otherwise the one I mentioned.Sqlite may not null terminate.

Comment: here cData contains sequence of nos <0d0a3120 496e2074 68652062 6567696e 6e696e67 20476f64 20637265 61746564 20746865 20686561 76656e20 616e6420 74686520 65617274....ans nStr has null value..

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSMutableArray *ar=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 NSString *strQuery=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select content from content where name = \"%@\" and chapterno = %@",chapName,chapNo];
 const char *sql =[mStr UTF8String];

    sqlite3_stmt *sqlStmt;
    if(sqlite3_open([self.dbPath UTF8String], &amp;database)==SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query, -1, &amp;compiledStmt, NULL)==SQLITE_OK){
         while (sqlite3_step(sqlStmt)==SQLITE_ROW) {
            len = sqlite3_column_bytes(sqlStmt, 0);
            NSData *cData = [[NSData alloc]initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(sqlStmt, 0) length:len];

            NSString *nstr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[cData bytes]];
            myTextView.text = nstr;

         [ar addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSData dataWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(compiledStmt, 1) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(compiledStmt, 1)],@"data1",
                                  [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStmt, 2)],@"data2",nil]];
    }
    else {
                NSLog(@"Invalid query");
            }
 NSArray *arToReturn=([ar count]>;0)?[NSArray arrayWithArray:ar]:nil;
        ar=nil;
return arToReturn;
    }
```

Please implement following code and let me inform any problem and query genrated.

Comment: If you want to still in trouble then please visit my blog post.http://goo.gl/5Q9zs

Comment: thanks for response and I tried this code..same prob, nothing is displaying error is new...prob is with prepare stmt:bind or column index out of range..

Comment: can you please enable zombie?

Comment: "[ar oddobj...] is giving bind or col index out of range...and nStr has null value.

Comment: Are complete follow my blog post or not?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a **simplest** alternate way for it.

Since, I am taking **book name**(from first table view) and **chapter number**(from second table view) from the database and passing it to detail view page.

Lets say here, my books names are maths, physics, geography..and chapters are in numerals (1,2,3...).Only thing is needed to keep the file name as

```
  [booknamechpatername.txt]
#book name- Maths
  chapter1-->> maths1.txt
  chapter2-->> maths2.txt
  ...
#book name - Physics
  chapter1 -->>  physics12.txt
  ...
  geography21.txt
 ...so on..
```

and drag it to iphone resource or any folder you want.
Now, Store that file into string and display into UITextView.

```
-(void)loadFile{
   NSError *error;
   NSArray *dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *docDir = [dirPath objectAtIndex:0];
   if (!docDir) {
       NSLog(@"Doc dir not found");
    }
   NSString *str = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",chapName,chapNo] ofType:@"txt"];

   NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:str encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
   myTextView.text = content;
}
```

and call it in **viewDidLoad**

```
 [self loadFile];
```

Otherwise, this link https://github.com/jblough/bible-ios would help, if you want to go through database only.